# Glass looking wierd in rendered result

Tags: rendering

[image]
That's the glass in the  rendered viewport shading. But when i render it, its coming out totally wierd. 
[image]

How do i go about this please

Comment: There is indeed some weirdness going on here - however it looks like the geometry might be different. As suggested, try to go through your modifier tree and see if anything there is odd. Alternatively could you provide a link to the file?

Comment: it looks like there is a solidify modifier in the preview but not in the render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have modifiers that are not visible in render mode, changing the way it will look. Make sure that *every* modifier is enabled for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much guys. I had the *use modifier during render* button turned off. Turned that on and the glass came out well.

Comment: Please don't use answers to write comments. In future put this in the comment section under your question.